# Query multiple SlideIn functions based on row number

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am looking for information on the best approach to creating a 'more details' section on a table generated by a MySQL query which is something like this:

```
<tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Surname</td>
  <th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Blogs</td>
  <td><a class="button-1" href="">More Details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="hidden_details hidden-1" colspan="3">...insert details...</th>
</tr>
```

Each row has a unique id e.g. button-2,3,4 etc that I can use to create a unique class for each details section and I can hide and show the details using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button-1').click(function(){
        var link = $(this);
        $('.hidden-1').slideToggle('slow', function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                 link.text('Hide Details');                
            } else {
                 link.text('More Details');                
            }        
        });       
    });
});
```

But my knowledge on JQuery is limited so the only way I could think to call the code would be to use php to create multiple versions. If anyone could point my in the direction of the best approach I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

check this code. it will help you. here id="view_1",id="show_1" 1 is your dynamic value from database .

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Surname</td>
  <th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td>Blogs</td>
  <td><a class="button-1" id="view_1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_details(1)">More Details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="hidden_details hidden-1" colspan="3" id="show_1">...insert details...</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Joe1</td>
  <td>Blogs2</td>
  <td><a class="button-1" id="view_2" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_details(2)">More Details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="hidden_details hidden-1" colspan="3" id="show_2">...insert details...</th>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function show_details(id) {
         if ($('#show_'+id).is(':visible')) {
                 $('#view_'+id).text('More Details');
                 $('#show_'+id).hide();                
            } else {
                 $('#view_'+id).text('Hide Details'); 

                 $('#show_'+id).show();               
            } 
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden_details {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```